# Adding Unique Sheets From Range Values

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, if-statement, worksheet-function

I am attempting to write code that runs through column G, and adds a new sheet for every unique value with out creating duplicates; However from what I have so so it creates duplicates

```
Public Sub AddSheet()
    Worksheets("Dataset").Select
    Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlToRight)).Name = "Title"
    Range("A2", Range("G1").End(xlDown)).Name = "Data"
    Range("H2", Range("H1").End(xlDown)).Name = "Physician"
    Dim i As Integer, lastrow As Integer
    lastrow = Worksheets("Dataset").Cells(Worksheets("Dataset").Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    With Range("Physician")
        For i = 1 To lastrow
            If i.Value = Worksheetexists = False Then
                Sheet.Add
                ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets("Dataset").Cells(i, 1).Value
            Else
                GoTo NextStep:
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I sense there is a question in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

something like this will iterate and create a new sheet for every unique value in Column A.

```
Public Sub AddSheet()
With Worksheets("Dataset")
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If IsError(Application.Evaluate("'" & .Cells(i, 1).Value & "'!A1")) And .Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            ws.Name = .Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, this code created new sheets up until there was a duplicate, then reported an error stating that name had already been taken and the sub stopped.

Comment: It did not do that with my test, did you change anything?  The `IsError(Application.Evaluate("'" & .Cells(i, 1).Value & "'!A1"))` should take care of duplicates.

Comment: So it should be "!A1" even if we are concerned with column H?

Comment: make sure you use the edit which added a catch if the worksheet name has spaces.  And no it does not matter, that is only checking if that cell exist on that sheet.  If the sheet does not exist it will throw an error.  the part inside the Evaluate should read: `"'" & .Cells(i, 1).Value & "'!A1"`.  I added the `'` to make it work with sheet names that have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work and be a bit safer as you may need to check the edge case that a sheet you are adding **already** exists. I'm using a dictionary to keep track of unique sheet names first, then adding to that based on the unique values in column H.

```
Sub SOExample()
    Dim DataSheet   As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim ws          As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lastRow     As Long
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim dict        As Object
    Dim SheetName   As String

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dataset")

    lastRow = DataSheet.Cells(DataSheet.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    'Add existing sheets into the dictionary first
    'in case a sheet already exists with that name
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        dict.Add ws.Name, ws.Name
    Next

    'Loop the range and add new sheets
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        SheetName = DataSheet.Cells(i, 8).Value 'Column H is index 8
        If Not dict.exists(SheetName) Then
            dict.Add SheetName, SheetName
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            ws.Name = SheetName
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```